# Is there any way to trigger my javascript modules to check whether they are working properly during load tests

Tags: arrays, load, jmeter

Is there any way to trigger my javascript modules in jmeter  to check whether they are working  properly during load/performance tests

Comment: Hello, you need to be more precise about What you mean by javascript modules

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser so it isn't able to execute client-side JavaScript. All that JMeter is able to do in this regards is:

- Download scripts along with other embedded resources like images and styles ([but do it only once per virtual user](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)) to simulate real browsers behavior more or less closely.
- Simulate JavaScript-driven calls like [AJAX/XHR via separate HTTP Requests](http://theworkaholic.blogspot.com/2010/11/jmeter-and-ajax-part-i.html)

The most common practice of web application monitoring during performance session is manually accessing the application under test and assessing it's responsiveness and behavior.

This process can also be automated using [JMeter's WebDriver Sampler Plugin](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which allows to invoke arbitrary Selenium code to orchestrate one or several real browsers to check i.e. actual page load speed during performance test session.